# If i set configuration at broker level and topic level, which takes precedence?

Tags: apache-kafka

As per the apache kakfa documentation, it seems i've an option to set 'min.insync.replicas' at broker level and topic level. Now my question is - If i set 'min.insync.replicas' at broker level and topic level, which takes precedence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The configuration at broker level having a relation to a topic serves as default values**. That means, if you create a topic without specifying topic configuration it will fall back to the configuration at broker level.

For example, topics that are automatically created (through `auto.create.topics.enable`) will use the configuration at broker level.

The details are given in the Kafka documentation in section [Topic-Level Configs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs)

> Configurations pertinent to topics have both a server default as well an optional per-topic override. If no per-topic configuration is given the server default is used. The override can be set at topic creation time by giving one or more --config options.